# How can I find a list of installed aptitude repositories on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm running this command when setting up new ubuntu servers

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable`

Is there a command I can run that will show that I've run this command and added `ppa:nginx/stable` as a repository?

Answer (score 3):

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: +1, but I feel like there should be a command designed to do this, so I'm going to wait to see what else comes in before accepting. Thanks.